# Unreliable guide to kernel locking

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, locking, mutex, spinlock

Can anyone explain this please.

The paragraph is from "Unreliable Guide To Locking" by Rusty Russel.
Link to the section, https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kernel-hacking/locking.html#locking-speed

> Acquisition times depend on how much damage the lock operations do to the pipeline (pipeline stalls) and how likely it is that this CPU was the last one to grab the lock (ie. is the lock cache-hot for this CPU): on a machine with more CPUs, this likelihood drops fast. Consider a 700MHz Intel Pentium III: an instruction takes about 0.7ns, an atomic increment takes about 58ns, a lock which is cache-hot on this CPU takes 160ns, and a cacheline transfer from another CPU takes an additional 170 to 360ns. (These figures from Paul McKenney’s Linux Journal RCU article)

Author talks about the **Acquisition Time** time taken to actually *acquire and release* an *uncontested* lock

And, this entity depends upon how much of the pipeline is being stalled because of the lock operation (I get how that might affect acquisition time, but I don't get the second part, which is) and '...how likely it is that this CPU was the last one to grab the lock (ie. is the lock cache-hot for this CPU): on a machine with more CPUs, this likelihood drops fast...'

Consider this scenario,

we have two instances of the **same program** running on **two different** CPUs. Both want to take the lock(L). I am assuming two separately pipelines with instructions a set of which are locking instructions.

So far, I don't understand how which cpu gets the lock last affects Acquisition time of the lock.
If both are contending both will have hot cache, still in case of spinlock case.

I tried reading it couple of times, expecting to understand it clearly.

Comment: There is shared cache and per-CPU cache.  This is talking about per-CPU cache. If the current CPU is not most recent, it needs to load from shared cache or RAM.

Comment: 'lock cache-hot for this CPU';

what contributes to "lock cache-hot"?

Comment: The paragraph you cite simply states that if the lock value is still in cache then it's faster to access it, otherwise a lower hierarchy cache access or an actual memory load needs to be made, slowing things down. What's unclear about this? It's basically the same concept that applies to any memory access: is the value in cache and valid? Yes -> fast; No -> slow.

Comment: If a lock is "cache-hot on this CPU" it means this CPU's cache has a valid value. Other CPU caches will not, and may therefore need to transfer the value to their cache from the other CPU cache. It's a classic [cache coherency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) problem.

Comment: Thanks, I got that part. if the lock value is already in cache it will be accessed faster.

What confused me was the part where we say the lock is uncontended, and the acquisition time depends on what cpu was the last one to grab the lock. Nevertheless, it's clear now. Again, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Also, '...on a machine with more CPUs, this likelihood drops fast...' from above; likelihood of what?